# Compare schema of dataframe with schema of other dataframe

Tags: java, scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have schema from two dataset read from hdfs path and it is defined below:

`val df = spark.read.parquet("/path")`

`df.printSchema()`

```
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- dept: integer (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your schema file seems like a CSV :

```
// Read and convert into a MAP  
val csvSchemaDf = spark.read.csv("/testschemafile")
val schemaMap = csvSchema.rdd.map(x => (x(0).toString.trim,x(1).toString.trim)).collectAsMap

var isSchemaMatching = true

//Iterate through the schema fields of your df and compare 
for( field <- df.schema.toList ){
  if( !(schemaMap.contains(field.name) && 
        field.dataType.toString.equals(schemaMap.get(field.name).get))){
      //Mismatch 
      isSchemaMatching = false;
  }
}
```

use `isSchemaMatching` for further logic

Answer (score 0):

You can create instance of StructType in the following way:

```scala
    val schema = StructType(
        Seq(
            StructField("name", StringType(), true),
            StructField("id", IntegerType(), true)
        ))
```

Just read the file and create schema based on data in file.

[Spark schema examples](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-schema-explained-with-examples/)
[Scaladoc of spark types](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.types.package)
[Spark type doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/sql-reference.html)